# Ember creating a record different than the current controller

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-rails

So I'm making a little toy ember app that will present a user with some improv prompts to create a comic strip out of. After a certain amount of time, the user will be able to upload their completed comic.

I've got the whole thing working up to the point of preseting the form to the user to upload their completed comic.

So far, everything is one route, controller and model (prompts). At the end though, they really should be working with a comic record. At the present, everything is in the same template, and I put the upload form into a view:

```
App.UploadComicView = Ember.View.extend
  templateName: "upload_comic"
  tagName: "form"
  classes: ['form-horizontal']

  submit: ->
    @get('controller').uploadComic(@get('comicTitle'))
    false
```

For the following model:

```
App.Comic = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
```

And I attempted to do the following in the prompts_controller:

```
uploadComic: (title) ->
  App.Comic.createRecord(title: title)
  @get('store').commit()
```

However, that attempts to sent a update action to the prompts controller on the backend, not a create request to the comics controller.

So it seems like I really should have a separate ember controller/template/model/route for comics, but I'm not sure how to get from the prompts controller at the end of the challenge to the comics controller in order to create a new comic object in the database. To make matters worse, I also really need to send the selected prompts from the current prompts controller to the new context.

What would be the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a `App.Comic.createRecord` it will do a `POST` to `/comics` with the request body `{title: 'your title'}`. This is regardless of which controller/location you do it from. Are you saying that it goes elsewhere? Please post a jsbin if this is the case.

Regarding the need to communicate with/access other controllers, you can use the `needs` declaration inside the other controller.

```
needs: 'comics'
comicsBinding: 'controllers.comics'
```

You can now access the comics controller via `this.get('comics')` inside it.

Comment: So I solved part of the problem, but I'm still not quite there. I assigned the new record to a variable `comic`, and then did `comic.get('store').commit()` which does save the record to the REST endpoint, however it also tries to persist the prompts, which shouldn't be updated at all (sends a `Started PUT "/prompts/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-03 09:46:46 -0400`) which fails because there is no update action in the api.

Comment: You can isolate the changes to the comic by using `transaction`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17440711/2488281).

Comment: Thanks, I'm having trouble getting transaction to work, so I started a new question on that. Thanks!