# How to update just 1 record in Ember.js with Ember-data? Currently save() and commit() on 1 record actually updates all records of model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

<strike>*Premise: My question is based on my research of Ember-data, which may or may not be correct. So please correct me if I have any misunderstanding. The examples are running with the latest ember as of July 2, 2013.*</strike>

To edit a record of my model, just 1 record, you need to call `this.get('store').commit()` or `this.get('model').save()`. However, downstream of either of these functions actually have to update **all** of the records of the model, even those left untouched. So this is quite inefficient, especially if the model has numerous records.

**What's the best way to update *one and only one* record when I'm saving the edits of one record?**

UPDATE: this problem only occurs for the [local-storage-adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L184), not the [RESTAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js).

UPDATE #2: I did have a huge misunderstanding. **Everything is okay, save() and commit() both update just 1 record, I've been fooled by local storage adapter `_saveData`'s [JSON.stringify(this._data)](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L184)** which printed out all records. I assumed that whatever it printed out was the data that is changed, but turns out in `_saveData`'s callers the `records` in [updateRecords](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L128) and [_didSaveRecords](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L170) were just the single record I was changing.  The statements below about different objects containing "all records of the model" can no longer be duplicated. I guess I misread the debugging information.
It makes sense because `_saveData` uses localstorage, which currently can only [setItem for an entire object](http://www.drdobbs.com/web-development/the-localstorage-api/240000682), which in my case is the model containing all the records. Since localstorage can't update individual entries of that object, the JSON must contain all the records.

---

<strike>Details:</strike>

Running Examples:

- `this.get('store').commit()` is used in `doneEditing` of [updating a post this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ajewot/4/edit).
- `this.get('model').save()` is used in `acceptChanges` of [updating a todo this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ikizat/2/edit).

If you turn on Chrome debug and walk into the above two functions, you'll see something similar to below:

1. Downstream, there is `currentTransaction` or `defaultTransaction`, and **both have all records of the model inside**.

   In the case of get('store').commit(), it eventually calls DS.Store's `commit`, which in turn calls: (see [github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L934-L941))

   ```
   get(this, 'defaultTransaction').commit();
   ```

   In the case of case of get('model').save(), it eventualy calls DS.Store's `scheduleSave` and `flushSavedRecords`, which call: (see [github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L943-L951))

   ```
   get(this, 'currentTransaction').add(record);
   get(this, 'currentTransaction').commit();
   ```

   Note at the end a `commit()` is called on xxxTransaction, this is DS.Transaction's `commit()`.
2. DS.Transaction`s`commit()`has a`commitDetails`, which is based on xxxTransaction, so`commitDetails` also has all the records of the data. ([github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/transaction.js#L194-L211))
3. Then DS.Adapter's `commit` and `save` are called and indeed every single record is updated ([github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L680-L682)):

   ```
   this.groupByType(commitDetails.updated).forEach(function(type, set) {
      this.updateRecords(store, type, filter(set));
   }, this);
   ```

   (minor side note/question: when was commitDetails set to "updated"?)

I know that DS.Adapter can be customized, but clearly the problem of saving more than one data (i.e. all of the model entries) are set from DS.Store's `commitDefaultTransaction` and `currentTransaction`.

Somehow I feel it would be a bad idea to tinker with DS.Store or anything upstream of DS.Adapter, like making my own version of save() and commit(). Basically I am reluctant to customize anything I'm told not to, since there might be ugly side effects.

**So what should I do if I want to use Ember data but can only afford to update one record only at a time?**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new transaction just for managing that record, using `transaction()` method of the `store`. This transaction has the same api as the `defaultTransaction`.

```
var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
transaction.add(model)
transaction.commit();
```

Committing this transaction won't affect other changes. See this [blog post](http://nragaz.com/post/44226445908/patterns-and-anti-patterns-for-ember-data) for further ideas.

Comment: This is replacing thing in the Store, is this good practice?  I thought we should only replace Adapter/Serializer.

Comment: No it doesn't replace from the Store. `transaction()` creates a new transaction wrapper. You can also do the same on the model/record via `model.get('store').transaction()`.